# Javascript redirection not working on facebook in app andriod browser?

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, redirect, facebook-browser

Javascript redirection has stopped working on the latest version of facebook in app andriod browser. Tried
`window.location.replace({url})`and also so many different methods with no avail.
including:

- Window.open Method
- Window.open with Target Method
- Eval with window.location.href
- SetTimeOut with window.location.href
- SetTimeOut with window.onload
- Window.location Method (Sets the new location of the current window.)
- Window.location.assign Method (Assigns a new URL to the current window.)
- Window.location.replace Method( Replaces the location of the current window with the new one. )
- Self.location Method (Sets the location of the current window itself. )
- Top.location Method (Sets the location of the topmost window of the current window.)
- Document.location.href
- Client Side Click Trigger
- Meta Refresh Method

Any suggestions as to why it is not working?

Comment: We have the same issue. link.click() also stopped working

Comment: Maybe they are trying to crack down on sites that try to present completely different stuff to users, than to the FB scraper (for which a simple client-side redirect via JS is an often used method.)

Comment: Not sure if remote debugging this thing using this approach still works, but if it does perhaps that could be a way to gain some insight (or get an error message that clears things up maybe), https://blog.tomayac.com/2019/12/09/inspecting-facebooks-webview/#looking-into-facebook's-iab

Comment: Will check this out. thanks

Comment: tried debugging on dev tools but no avail. It is loading the same page

Comment: v323.0.0.46.119 is the version which had issue. The new version v324.0.0.48.120 doesn't have this bug.